# Why do I get a segmentation fault in my C++ sudoku checker?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm actually coding on codingame.com and I get a segmentation fault in my program that doesn't make sense to me.

I created a Grid class, which is basically a 2D array of (9*9) char and a couple of checking functions.

My public check() calls private checkLine(), checkRow() and checkSquare(). Each of these 3 in turn call checkNine().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid(string str)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
            {
                this->sudoku[i/9][i%9] = str[i];
            }
        }
        string check()
        {
            bool result = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                result = result && checkLine(i) && checkRow(i);
            }
            return result ? "true" : "false";
        }
    private:
        bool checkLine(int line)
        {
            cerr << "line:" << line << endl;
            vector<char> vec;
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                vec.push_back(this->sudoku[line][j]);
            }
            return checkNine(vec);
        }
        bool checkRow(int row)
        {
            cerr << "row:" << row << endl;
            vector<char> vec;
            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            {
                  vec.push_back(this->sudoku[k][row]);
            }
            return checkNine(vec);
        }
        bool checkNine(vector<char> nine)
        {
            array<int, 9> tmp;
            tmp.fill(0);
            for(int m = 0; m < 9; m++)
            {
                tmp[nine[m - '0']] = tmp[nine[m - '0']] + 1;
            }

            return true;
        }
        char sudoku[9][9];
};

int main()
{
    string str;
    str = "123456789456789123789123456912345678345678912678912345891234567234567891567891234";

    Grid grid(str);
    cout << grid.check() << endl;
}
```

As you can see, I put cerr statements to try to see what was happening.

When I try to run the program, this is what I get:

```
Erreurs
Segmentation fault.
at new_allocator.h. function __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffe8d0, __p=0x55565556ef50 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x55565556ef50>) on line 128
at alloc_traits.h. function std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate (__a=..., __p=0x55565556ef50 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x55565556ef50>, __n=18446744069414584329) on line 470
at stl_vector.h. function std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffe8d0, __p=0x55565556ef50 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x55565556ef50>, __n=18446744069414584329) on line 351
at stl_vector.h. function std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffe8d0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) on line 332
at stl_vector.h. function std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffe8d0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) on line 680
at Answer.cpp. function Grid::checkLine (this=0x7fffffffe950, line=0) on line 37
at Answer.cpp. function Grid::check[abi:cxx11]() (this=0x7fffffffe950) on line 24
at Answer.cpp. function main () on line 94
Sortie standard :
line:0
row:0
```

where line 37 is "vec.push_back(this->sudoku[line][j]);"

Could anyone send me in the right direction ?

*Edit: Sidenote, my checkNine() is not finished, it always returns true, but that's not the point.*

Comment: You get `line:0 row:1` without any other outputs before that?

Comment: Please provide a [example] that reproduces the error (actually make sure it reproduced the error). If you need help making one let us know.

Comment: @CarlosN exactly, these are my only two outputs.

Comment: Do you want us to debug your program for you?  What are the results of your debugging session?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint at line 45 and examined the variables?

Comment: I do not see a program.  I see a class called `Grid`, with member functions.  A program requires a `main` function that utilizes the `Grid`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie okay, I'll add the main function

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the codingame website has an integrated IDE that doesn't have a debugger. I don't have access to a computer on which I can install one right now. Sorry if I'm making you lose your time, I thought it might be a stupid "obvious" error that I couldn't see.

Comment: Instead of calling `getline`, please assign the data directly into the string.  We don't know what the input consists of.  I would expect, `Grid grid("some string of digits");`, and not input routines.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I don't understand how to make a minimal reproducible example here... Do I get read of the class, and just make the two functions and call them the same way ?

Comment: @Chiwaruchk -- *I don't understand how to make a minimal reproducible example here* -- See my comment.  Initialize the `Grid` instance with a known string of data that causes the issue.  Get rid of the `for` loop in `main`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OK, I think I removed all unnecessary parts in my example and I put the string directly in the main. The same error is still there, so I know it's in what I left.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think I agree there... I want my tmp array to hold 9 digits. A Sudoku grid can only contain numbers from 1 to 9. But now, telling you that, I actually found my error... Discussion is so helpful and can trigger good things. The correct answer is the line should be : tmp[nine[i - '0' - 1]] = tmp[nine[i - '0' - 1]] + 1; because I check values '1' to '9' in an array 0 to 8

Comment: The array of size 10 go from 0 to 9.  Where are you going to store `tmp[9]`?  If you declare an array of only 9, the highest index is 8.  Remember that arrays are 0-based in C++, thus if you want to have something going from 1-9, you either declare an array of 10 and leave the 0 index entry alone, or declare an array of 9 and subtract 1 from all your index calculations.  The former is easier than the latter in your case, and the former is the original intent of your code.

Comment: Yes it's easier, but it defeats the purpose of my function. It counts how many times each number (in the form of a char)  is present, and in the end, if one of the number is missing (one of the values of the array is still 0) then the check fails.

Comment: There is an even easier check: `return std::unordered_set<char>(nine.begin(), nine.end()).size() == 9;` 
`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with unordered_set... Does it mean that if there would be two same entries in the vector<char>, the second entry wouldn't be initialized in the unordered_set because the keys have to be unique?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  So if you are supposed to have unique `1-9`, then the set size is going to be 9 if the items are unique.  Also, you shouldn't change the code in the original question -- just make the changes to your local program.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful, beyond my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

```
bool checkNine(vector<char> nine)
{
    array<int, 9> tmp;  // <-- Too small, it has to hold 10 digits
    tmp.fill(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        tmp[nine[i]] = tmp[nine[i]] + 1; // <-- Out of bounds access
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `nine` vector holds `char` values.  Those `char` values are character representations of the digits.  However the `tmp` array assumes `int` versions of the digit, not `char` types.

In short, you are (for example) assuming that `'2' == 2`, and that is not the case.

Thus you need to convert the `char` to the `int` version:

```
tmp[nine[i] - '0'] = tmp[nine[i] -'0'] + 1;
```

---

The other error is that `tmp` has to hold 10 digits, thus the array is too small.  It should have a size of `10`, not `9`.

```
    array<int, 10> tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, that was one of the "obvious" mistakes I was mentioning in a previous comment. I still have exactly the same error, but now the cerr output is row:0.

Comment: So the segmentation fault no longer occurs?

Comment: Oh no, it still does, the only change is the row:0 instead of row:1.

Comment: Then you need to supply the data -- see the comment in the main section.